# How to call a variable from one function into another function?

Tags: python, function, import

**Note: this is a very long question.**

I'm practicing python by making a game. I need to take a variable from another function (that I called `spawn()`) and use in a different function (that I called `damage_taken()`).

This is the file `enemy.py`. Its main job is to spawn an enemy:

```
import random
import player

class Enemy(object):

    def types(self):
        type = ["slime", "ghost", "demon"]
        enemy = random.choice(type)
        return enemy


class Slime(Enemy):

    def types(self):
        colour = ["red", "green", "blue"]
        type = random.choice(colour)
        return type

    def health(self):
        health = random.randint(1,5)
        return health


class Ghost(Enemy):

    def types(self):
        form = ["spirit", "spectre", "phantom"]
        type = random.choice(form)
        return type

    def health(self):
        health = random.randint(10,30)
        return health


class Demon(Enemy):

    def types(self):
        being = ["demon", "hell hound", "wendigo"]
        type = random.choice(being)
        return type

    def health(self):
        health = random.randint(15,35)
        return health
```

This is the important code. I need to take the variable `health` from this function and use it in another function.

```
def spawn():
    enemy = Enemy()
    bad = enemy.types()

    if bad == "slime":
        slime = Slime()
        target = slime.types()
        health = slime.health()
        print(f"A {target} {bad} has appeared. It has {health} HP")
        return health
    elif bad == "ghost":
        ghost = Ghost()
        target = ghost.types()
        health = ghost.health()
        print(f"A {target} has appeared. It has {health} HP")
        return health
    elif bad == "demon":
        demon = Demon()
        target = demon.types()
        health = demon.health()
        print(f"A {target} has appeared. It has {health} HP")
        return health
```

**This is where i am struggling**. I am trying to take the variable `health` from the function `spawn()` and use it in the following function. However, it keeps on telling me `health` does not exist. How do i take a variable from another function and use it in this function.

```
def damage_taken():
    spawn()
    health = spawn.health - player.fight()
    return health

damage_taken()
```

The code

```
spawn.health
```

is my failed attempt at trying to call the variable into the function.

The code:

```
player.fight()
```

is calling a function from a different file called `player.py`. Its main purpose is to deal with mechanics related to the player such as creating the character and deciding how much damage they deal.

Comment: It's not clear what your actual *question* is. Cut this down to a [mcve].

Comment: when `spawn` is a function, what `spawn.health` means? in file enemy.py into damage_taken function?

Comment: @Hameda169 Pretty clear what he meant is to be able to access health value under spawn()

Comment: Just call spawn() and store its return value under variable

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood your question you just need to assign the return value from your spawn function into a variable:

```
def damage_taken():
    spawn_health = spawn()
    health = spawn_health - player.fight()
    return health
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you would actually rather the `spawn` function, return the enemy object, rather than the `health` of the enemy, so I would recommend the following:

```
def spawn():
    enemy = Enemy()
    bad = enemy.types()

    if bad == "slime":
        enemy = Slime()  # each of these now is assigned to the same variable name, "enemy"
        target = slime.types()
        health = slime.health()
        print(f"A {target} {bad} has appeared. It has {health} HP")
    elif bad == "ghost":
        enemy = Ghost()
        target = ghost.types()
        health = ghost.health()
        print(f"A {target} has appeared. It has {health} HP")
    elif bad == "demon":
        enemy = Demon()
        target = demon.types()
        health = demon.health()
        print(f"A {target} has appeared. It has {health} HP")

    return enemy

def damage_taken():
    enemy = spawn()
    health = enemy.health - player.fight()
    return health
damage_taken()
```

now, there is still the problem that the enemy object will be entirely dropped after `damage_taken()` is called. If you want the enemy to persist, you likely will want to initialize both player and enemy outside of the scope of the `damage_taken` function.  Something more like this:

```
enemy = spawn()
damage_taken(enemy)
```